# How to configure correct timezone in JDBC?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, timezone, spring-jdbc

I've this url to set up the connection in my Italy website, however, when i try to perform some insert action from the site, the date is still not right. (it should be for example: 01:24, but it is 02:24)

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://sql.example.com/database?autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&sessionVariables=time_zone='Europe/Rome'
```

Do I need to add any other params to make it work correctly?
Is there a complete list of all timezones?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry I don't have the answer to your direct question. However I can suggest something worth considering that will avoid all time zone problems at the database entirely. If possible I recommend simply using `BIGINT` fields for storing dates with Java. You just store the `long` of the number of milliseconds since the epoch, e.g. from `System.currentTimeMillis()` or `Date.getTime()`.

Then interpretation of the time zone for a date is always managed in Java, which is good at using the epoch based number. It does make it a little more involved to directly query the database for a date outside of Java, however it's not too hard and tends to be worth it IMO:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(date_field / 1000) FROM table;
```

Comment: Ouh, good point! Thank you, will see about doing it this way!

Answer (score 1):

There is a list of "tz" timezone names in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones).