# store date in database

Tags: java, database, date

I have a JSP page in which I am entering a date in a textbox and retrieving the value from the textbox and the value is stored in a string variable. I want to convert this value to date and that value will be stored in database. I use MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SimpleDateFormat.parse()` to parse your date string into a `Date` object and store that or the `getTime()` of that in the database.

Here's an example of parsing the date:

```
String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy";
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
Date date = format.parse("03/24/2011");
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5399563/how-to-configure-correct-timezone-in-jdbc/5399804#5399804) about storing dates in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to convert your date String into a `java.sql.Date` object, like so

```
java.sql.Date date = java.sql.Date.valueOf("2011-01-12"); //where date is of pattern "yyyy-MM-dd"
```

Once date is created, use the `PreparedStatement.setDate(int index, java.sql.Date date)` to store the date in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If - for now - you do not need the actual Date in your program you can just call setString on the appropriate field in the prepared statement to have the database parse the date.

Answer (score 0):

I would always store a value that does not depend on a timezone in a database; `Date.getTime()` does nicely and can always be converted to something you can display or work with otherwise, and it avoids lots of troubles when it comes to daylight saving time.